# Bold words that start with letter

Tags: swift

I want to set a label's text with a string that's partly bold. The words I want to make bold all begin with the same letter, say "~".

For example I could have the string, "This ~word is bold, and so is ~this"

Then the label's text would contain the string "This **word** is bold, and so is **this**".

Does anybody know if it's possible to make a function like this? I tried the following:

```
func makeStringBoldForLabel(str: String) {
    var finalStr = ""
    let words = str.components(separatedBy: " ")
    for var word in words {
        if word.characters.first == "~" {
            var att = [NSFontAttributeName : boldFont]
            let realWord = word.substring(from: word.startIndex)
            finalStr = finalStr + NSMutableAttributedString(string:realWord, attributes:att)
        } else {
            finalStr = finalStr + word
        }
    }
}
```

but get the error:

`Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'NSMutableAttributedString'`

Answer (score 0):

Easy to solve problem.

use:

```
func makeStringBoldForLabel(str: String) {
    let finalStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
    let words = str.components(separatedBy: " ")
    for var word in words {
        if word.characters.first == "~" {
            var att = [NSFontAttributeName : boldFont]
            let realWord = word.substring(from: word.startIndex)
            finalStr.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string:realWord, attributes:att))
        } else {
            finalStr.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: word))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error happens on the line 'finalStr = finalStr + NSMutableAttributedString(string:realWord, attributes:att)' and if I cast 'finalStr' as an nsmutableattributedstring I get an error saying I can't add 2 nsmutableattributedstrings

Comment: Ahhh. I updated the answer. This should solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is that you can't use '+' on NSMutableAttributedStrings. Instead you have to use .append().

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear, you cannot concatenate `String` and `NSAttributedString` with the `+` operator.

You are looking for the API `enumerateSubstrings:options`. It enumerates strings word by word passing the `.byWords` option. Unfortunately the tilde (`~`) is not recognized as a word separator, so we have to check if a word has a preceding tilde. Then change the font attributes at the specific range.

```
let string = "This ~word is bold, and so is ~this"

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes:[NSFontAttributeName : NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
let boldAttribute = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)

string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..<string.endIndex, options: .byWords) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
    if substring == nil { return }
    if substringRange.lowerBound != string.startIndex {
        let tildeIndex = string.index(before: substringRange.lowerBound)
        if string[tildeIndex..<substringRange.lowerBound] == "~" {
            let location = string.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: tildeIndex)
            let length = string.distance(from: tildeIndex, to: substringRange.upperBound)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: boldAttribute, range: NSMakeRange(location, length))
        }
    }
}
```