# Read long paragraph of text from plist into a specific format with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview, plist, nsattributedstring

I am currently writing my first app on ios using swift 3. I have a plist that has a list of different pieces of information and each is a long paragraph with sections throughout it. for each section, I want to bold the text for the title or at least have the option to format it a certain way rather than just display all the text. I currently have a simple table view that displays text in a text view once tapped. I cannot figure out how to read the paragraph into a string, and compare parts of the string and bold that specific text.

For example, If I had a string that was read from the plist and said:

"My name is @Bob and I like to @dance."

How could I change "@Bob" to "**Bob**" and "@dance" to "**dance**" without hard coding it?

```
@IBOutlet var paragraphTextView: UITextView!
.
.
.

if let text = paragraph["Text"] {
        paragraphTextView.text = text
}
```

Comment: Sorry but you can do this only with `AttributedString`
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield#1968630

Comment: This might be a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557044/bold-words-that-start-with-letter/43557605#43557605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use some HTML markup in the text in your plist file.

Instead of the plain text:

> My name is @Bob and I like to @dance.

Use:

> My name is <b>Bob</b> and I like to <b>dance</b>.

This gives you far more flexibility. You can add bold, underline, and italic simply by using the appropriate `<b></b>`, `<u></u>`, and `<i></i>` tags as needed. It also allows you to markup more general ranges than single words.

Once the text has the proper markup, you create an `NSAttributedString` from the marked up string and then set that to the text view`s`attributedText`property instead of using the`text` property.

For a good example of how to create an `NSAttributedString` from HTML text, see [HTML Format in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414999/html-format-in-uitextview)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will try this, but I have no doubt it will work. I was looking for something like this but I guess was unsure if it was possible.

Comment: EDIT: It worked exactly as planned. Thank you very much!

Comment: How did you get the <b> </b> to work inside a plist which is already XML?? I get this error message; error: unable to read input file as a property list: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.)

Comment: @user3561494 You escape the `<` as `&lt;` just like any normal XML.